# Как называется стиль кода, когда функция объекта возвращает себя же?

Tags: java

Пример:

```
myVar
  .setColor(RED)
  .setStyle(BOLD)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java

Comment: Только возвращает не себя, а возвращает объект, на котором была вызвана.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это называется *"цепочка"* ([Method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining))

Comment: +1 Подвид цепочки в котором используется один и тот же класс называется [Method cascading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading)